# Split String based on Next Alphanumeric Character

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, split

I have a string:

```
Membership information ----------------------     Nodeid      Votes Name         2          1 MXQSRV2         1          1 pve (local)
```

the data i need is:

`2          1 MXQSRV2         1          1 pve (local)`

This Translates to:

```
Nodeid(Needed)    Votes(Can be thrown away)     Name(Needed) Nodeid(Needed)    Votes(Can be thrown away)     Name(Needed)
```

My Desired result is a listbox that displays:

*1 pve*

*2 MXQSRV2*

> This means: NodeID Name

**but can adapt if that list is longer**

I need the first of the two numbers in front of the Name, The second number can be discarded, and then the Name.
The Code I have so far is:

```
    Dim phaze2 As String = Replace(input, " (local)", "")
    Dim phaze3 As String = Replace(phaze2, "Membership information", "")
    Dim phaze4 As String = Replace(phaze3, "----------------------", "")
    Dim phaze5 As String = Replace(phaze4, "Node", "")
    Dim phaze6 As String = Replace(phaze5, "id", "")
    Dim phaze7 As String = Replace(phaze6, "Votes", "")
    Dim phaze8 As String = Replace(phaze7, "Name", "")
    Dim phaze9 As String = Replace(phaze8, " ", "")
```

and this returns:

```
*return*
*return*
*return*
*return*
21 MXQSRV2
11 pve
*return*
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Will your string always look like that?

Comment: yes it will always be identical in format but the content can get longer in the same pattern

Comment: Then the best option for you would probably be to replace all multi-spaces with tabs, and then split the string on tabs using `String.Split()`. I will post an example momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your string data will be consistent, you can remove extra padding and then split the string, like this:

```
While data.Contains("  ")
    data = data.replace("  ", " ")
End While


Dim values() as string = data.split(" ")
```

Once you have done this, you can get your values as needed by using the index of your field and concatenating the values. For example:

```
Label1.Text = values(3) & " " & values(7)
```